# Dplyr R: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sequence dataset that I am trying to determine the order of the sequence based on the date difference (should be > £) of observations and three other conditions.

I chose to use mutate to create an order column whose value is a counter that orders the records based on the date difference between the two records and if the observations meet a certain condition (mycheckfunc()).

```
  dt <- dt %>%
  group_by(obsID) %>%
  arrange(row_index)%>%
  mutate(order = ifelse(row_index == 1, 1, 
                           ifelse(dateDiff > 3, 1,
                                  ifelse(mycheckfunc(lag(x), y, z,), 0, 1))))
```

The mycheck is as below and works when tested separately

```
mycheckfunc<- function(x, y, z){

    if ((x %in% c(49,50,51,52,53,84)) | 
        (y %in% c(49,50,51,52,53,87)) | 
        (z %in% c("2B",81))){ 
      if(x == 19 & y == 51 & z == 21){
        return (FALSE) 
        }else{
          return (TRUE)
          }
      }else{
        return (FALSE)
      }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

```
obsID row_index dateDiff    x   y   z  order
1     1          NA        19  20  15   1
1     2          0         19  51  21   1
1     3          2         49   1   1   2
1     4          0         1   49   1   3
2     1          NA        19   21  2B  1
2     2         381        ..   .. ..   1
```

I was not able to update the order using the above code so I settled for the following output that only flags observations identified as the first in the sequence.

```
 obsID row_index dateDiff    x   y   z  order
    1     1          NA      19  20  15   1
    1     2          0       19  51  21   1
    1     3          2       49   1   1   0
    1     4          0        1   49  1   0
    2     1          NA      19   21  2B  1
    2     2         381      ..   .. ..   1
```

However I get the following error and warnings

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In if (x %in% c(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 84) | y %in% c(49, 50, 51, 52,  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ```

To note: I only have NAs in the dateDiff column which I think I have controlled for the the second ifelse statement in the mutate. i do not know why the mycheckfunc is returning NAs.. Please help.

> I've played around with the mutate a bit and realized the lag() is causing the problem. However because I'm only obtaining the lag for rows with predecessors it should not be null.. still stomped. I have the traceback below

```
14: stop(list(message = "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", 
        call = mutate_impl(.data, dots), cppstack = NULL))
13: .Call("dplyr_mutate_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", df, dots)
12: mutate_impl(.data, dots)
11: mutate_.tbl_df(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
10: mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
9: mutate(., spOrder = ifelse(row_index == 1, 1, ifelse(dateDiff >
```

> Ok so the problem was a rookie mistake: using if statements in the custom vector. The mutate uses a vectorised list of elements while my function was using if statement which does not therefore converted it to ifelse statements.

However does anyone know how I can update the ordering based on the above conditions to obtain table 1?

Comment: The warning message has got to do with how the “or” operator works (“|”): if you check for if(a %in% c(4,5,6) | b%in% c(7,10)) the idea is that the code only need to check if a is in 4, 5 or 6; if it is then it would evaluate to TRUE. You may need to edit the code to: if((a %in% c(4,5,6)) | (b%in% c(7,10))) so both of these conditions are executed and if any of these are TRUE then the enclosing condition evaluated to TRUE

Comment: Traceback() will give more Information. And an example would help.

Comment: I realized the lag in the mutate is causing the issue (see updated code) have added the traceback.

Comment: I still get the warnings even after enclosing the individual if conditions in brackets. :(

Comment: The simple way to vectorize a non-vectorized function is to use an `*apply` function. Have you tried that?