# trendecon to download Google Trends data: Problem with `mutate()` column `trend_data`

Tags: r, google-trends, gtrendsr

I'm using the [trendecon package](https://trendecon.github.io/trendecon/articles/intro.html) to download daily data from Google Trends. This package uses [gtrendsr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtrendsR/gtrendsR.pdf) under the hood, but creates many requests to create daily data for long periods of time (by default, Google doesn't give you daily data unless your search is less than 9 months). The command "proc_keyword_init" downloads daily, weekly, and monthly data for a given term and a given region.

I have been using the package for a while successfully, but starting yesterday all of my searches yield an error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `trend_data`. i `trend_data = list(...)`. x missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed i The error occurred in row 1.

From other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045786/dplyr-r-missing-value-where-true-false-needed) and [pages](https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/r-error-missing-value-where-true-false-needed/) I've found, this error is usually discussed when dealing with a dataset, but I haven't seen it discussed in a context like this where someone is downloading data.

I have tried reinstalling the trendecon package a couple of time, including with dependencies. I've also tried in three different versions of R across two computers, and I'm getting the same error. The error persists even when trying queries I had successfully used previously.

Here is an example of code and output:

```
library(trendecon)
proc_keyword_init("/m/0866r", "IR") # this downloads searches for the topic "weather" in Iran; topics are language-independent, [as you can see the top searches for this topic](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now%201-d&geo=IR&q=%2Fm%2F0866r&hl=en)
```

Output:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `trend_data`. i `trend_data = list(...)`. x missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed i The error occurred in row 1. Backtrace: 1. trendecon::proc_keyword_init("weather", "IR") 14. base::.handleSimpleError(...) 15. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
18.
stop(fallback)
17.
signal_abort(cnd)
16.
abort(bullets, class = c("dplyr:::mutate_error", "dplyr_error"), error_name = error_name, error_expression = error_expression, parent = e, bullets = bullets)
15.
h(simpleError(msg, call))
14.
.handleSimpleError(function (e) { local_call_step(dots = dots, .index = i, .fn = "mutate", .dot_data = inherits(e, "rlang_error_data_pronoun_not_found")) ...
13.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
12.
lapply(gtrendslist, get_ts_from_gtrends)
11.
ts_gtrends(keyword, category, geo, window, retry, wait, quiet)
10.
mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
9.
withCallingHandlers({ for (i in seq_along(dots)) { mask$across_cache_reset() context_poke("column", old_current_column) ...
8.
mutate_cols(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
7.
mutate.data.frame(., trend_data = list(ts_gtrends(keyword, category, geo, window, retry, wait, quiet)))
6.
mutate(., trend_data = list(ts_gtrends(keyword, category, geo, window, retry, wait, quiet)))
5.
unnest(., cols = trend_data)
4.
ungroup(.)
3.
tbl %>% mutate(trend_data = list(ts_gtrends(keyword, category, geo, window, retry, wait, quiet))) %>% unnest(cols = trend_data) %>% ungroup()
2.
ts_gtrends_windows(keyword = keyword, geo = geo, from = from, stepsize = "15 days", windowsize = "6 months", n_windows = floor(as.numeric(Sys.Date() - as.Date(from))/15), wait = 20, retry = 10, prevent_window_shrinkage = TRUE)
1.
proc_keyword_init("/m/0866r", "IR")
```